# Biase of ASE estimation Kernel Regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, smoothing

I'm trying to calculate the bias of the estimator $p(h)=n^{-1}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_{j}-\hat{m}_{h}(X_{j})^{2}w(X_{j})$ of the averaged squared error. The result I find in the literature is this:

[image]

but I am not able to calculate the expectation of the term $C_{1n}(h)$. Any idea of how to proceed or where to find it?

Comment: You may want to try substituting $Y_i = m(X_i) + \epsilon_i$ into (5.1.1).

Comment: it worked, thanks!